# Format Table not working correctly

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to display the results of my query below in a table format so the header just appears once at the top and the data below it. The code below is repeating the header for each row created. Is there a way to fix this when using FT-Auto? TIA

Sample Output:

```
Name Number of computers Package advertised Success Remaining computers

CH          19                  0       0                  19
```

---

```
foreach ($ou in $ou_l)
{

    $cmplist=get-adcomputer -Filter "cn -like '*L'"  -searchbase $ou.distinguishedname -Properties memberof
    $testcmplist=$cmplist | where {$_.memberof -like "*Test(P)*"}
    $NOTcmplist=$cmplist | where {$_.memberof -ne "Test(P)"}
    $pkgadv=$cmplist | where {$Members -LIKE $_.Name}
    $ou| select Name,
    @{n="Number of computers";e={$cmplist.count}},
    @{n="Package advertised";e={$testcmplist.count }},
        @{n="Success";e={$pkgadv.Count }},
        @{n="Remaining computers";e={$NOTcmplist.count }} | ft -auto
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your output?

Comment: Sure, I just updated to what it is currently showing. I would like it to be just one header and data below it?

Comment: Okay, so you want all OUs to report within a single table and right now you are getting a separate table for each OU.

Comment: Yes, sorry I had to correct the output above. Yes it is a separate table for each ou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as moving your Format-Table call to outside the ForEach loop like this

```
$ou_l | ForEach-Object {
    $ou = $_

    $cmplist=get-adcomputer -Filter "cn -like '*L'" -searchbase $ou.distinguishedname -Properties memberof
    $testcmplist=$cmplist | where {$_.memberof -like "*Test(P)*"}
    $NOTcmplist=$cmplist | where {$_.memberof -ne "Test(P)"}
    $pkgadv=$cmplist | where {$Members -LIKE $_.Name}

    $ou | Select Name, `
        @{n="Number of computers";e={$cmplist.count}}, `
        @{n="Package advertised";e={$testcmplist.count }}, `
        @{n="Success";e={$pkgadv.Count }}, `
        @{n="Remaining computers";e={$NOTcmplist.count }}
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

As you have it written, each record will be formatted as a separate table, not the adjusted list of records.

Comment: When I try that I get an error that an "Empty pipeline is not allowed?

Comment: I modified my code to include the ` to allow the Select to run across several lines.

Comment: I don't see where the ' is?

Comment: It is at the end of each line:  $ou | Select Name, `

Comment: Thanks I am trying that now it says I am missing terminator at the end?

Comment: Make sure that you do not put the ` on the very last line of the select @{n="Remaining Computers"...

Comment: I am back to the pipeline error if I don't have it on the last line, sorry I don't know what I am missing here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60538/discussion-between-brandon-and-user1342164).